Issues with Duplicate Job Execution in PM2 Node.js Application
I am running a Node.js application with PM2, consisting of two instances of fp-api, so it executing twice. so i create separate instance of ad-hoc-reporter. The ad-hoc-reporter is responsible for generating reports based on data fetched from a database.
see this is the ecosystem.js file
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
      name: 'fp-api',
      script: '/opt/statsd_api_gw/app.js',
      instances: 'max',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      autorestart: true,
      watch: ["/opt/statsd_api_gw/routes", "/opt/statsd_api_gw/encryption"],
      watch_delay: 1000,
      ignore_watch : ["node_modules", "client/img", "public"],
      error_file: '/opt/statsd_api_gw/logs/err.log',
      out_file: '/opt/statsd_api_gw/logs/out.log',
      time: true,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        INSTANCE_NAME: 'fp-api' // Set the instance name
      },
      env_production: {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        INSTANCE_NAME: 'fp-api' // Set the instance name
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'ad-hoc-reporter',
      script: '/opt/statsd_api_gw/routes/ad_hoc_report.js',
      instances: 1,
      exec_mode: 'fork',
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      error_file: '/opt/statsd_api_gw/logs/ad_hoc_err.log',
      out_file: '/opt/statsd_api_gw/logs/ad_hoc_out.log',
      time: true,
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        INSTANCE_NAME: 'ad-hoc-reporter' // Set the instance name
      },
      env_production: {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        INSTANCE_NAME: 'ad-hoc-reporter' // Set the instance name
      }
    }
  ]
}

but every request is pointing to fp-api, how its doing
//app.js
mountRoutes(app)
    https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/opt/statsd_api_gw/encryption/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/opt/statsd_api_gw/encryption/server.cert'),
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    app).listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('FatPipe API listening on port 443')
})

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(301, {"Location": "https://" + req.headers['host'] + req.url})
    res.end()
}).listen(80)

//index.js has rotes paths
const conn_stats = require('./connection_stats.js');
const health = require('./health.js');
const ad_hoc_report = require('./ad_hoc_report.js');

const API_VERSION = "v1";
const BASE_URL = "/fp/api/";

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(BASE_URL + API_VERSION, verify_api);
  app.use(BASE_URL + API_VERSION + '/connectionstats', conn_stats); 
  app.use(BASE_URL + API_VERSION + '/health', health);
  
  if (process.env.INSTANCE_NAME === 'ad-hoc-reporter') {
    console.log('Loading ad_hoc_report routes on', process.env.INSTANCE_NAME);
    app.use(BASE_URL + API_VERSION + '/adhocreport', ad_hoc_report);
  } else {
    console.log('Not loading ad_hoc_report routes on', process.env.INSTANCE_NAME);
  }
};

Thanks Advance.
I tried to create instance, if i do reload all its then its working and creating jobs on that server but if the request is coming from UI its always pointing fp api instance.
